# Toilet question

Tags: plumbing

What does it mean when water shoots out of toilet all by itself. Not after flushing. I woke to what I thought was rain only to learn it was water shooting out of my toilet

Comment: Out of the bowl of the toilet? Or the tank on the back where the water inlet connects?

Answer (score -1):

Shut off the main water supply to the house or the water supply to the toilet (whichever is faster and easier.)

If it persists, generally something is very wrong with a sewer line, and you should contact the sewer department ASAP. "Shooting out" is pretty much never a scenario with a septic system, so sewer is assumed.

If it stops, sometimes one does get inlet valve failures that cause water to come out.